# How is it possible that null-coalescing operator results in error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

This is weird.

This is related to the article "Using OAuth 2.0 with Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)": https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc

Disregard the entire code, no need, the question is this - there is a method:

```
public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
{
    private static string userId;

    public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
    {
        if (userId == null)
        {
            userId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        return userId;
    }
}
```

works like a charm, **never fails**.

The weird thing is - if I use null-coalescing operator (??) instead of IF block:

```
    public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
    {
        return userId ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
```

it fails **constantly**, trowing an exception:

> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException:
>   Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Invalid code.", Uri:""

Honestly, I believe these 2 codes must have identical effect. According to MSDN:

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the
>   left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the
>   right hand operand.

Can someone explain that to me ? :)

**Update** My bad, indeed in the second code there is no assignment of new Guid to userId. It should be like this instead:

```
userId = userId ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
return userId;
```

Comment: Why would it fail? Of course not.

Comment: Damn, you right. There is no SET of new Guid to userId var. It is just returned through a property GetUserId. Thanks Man. Such tiny things could easily be missed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These 2 methods are not the same.

The first will return the same GUID with each call (as long as `userID` is not set elsewhere).

The second will return a different GUID with each call (unless `userID` is set elsewhere to something not `null`).

Comment: @ZevSpitz subsequent may return different UserID in case of second method and throw that exception

Comment: @ZevSpitz The answer explains why the system behaves differently when the 2nd method is used. It doesn't explain why it results in an exception (I don't know that), but I think it can help the OP understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry, the userId is declared above this method. I Changed the code in the post. But how is it relevant? Doesnt change anything.

Comment: Thanks man, There is no SET of new Guid to userId var in the second code. It is just returned through a property GetUserId. Thanks Man. Such tiny things could easily be missed :)